# Linear independence of a set of vectors and vectors alone

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear algebra book with definition of linear independence like:
"Let $x_1, x_2, ..., x_k$ be vectors in $L$. If $k\geq2$, then the vectors $x_1, x_2, ..., x_k$ are said to be linearly dependent..."

And there are some problems (they aren't written in English, so I translate them):  Find out if a group of vectors is linear dependent or not.

I don't understand what is meant by "a group of vectors". I've tried to read about groups, but I don't think that a mathematical group and a group of vectors in my book are similar groups. In addition, all definitions which I found on Wikipedia (in different languages) are definitions of linear independence of a **set**, not just a "group" of vectors.

What does that mean? Can we talk about linear independence of something which is not a set?

Comment: It is overwhelmingly likely that the problem text you translate as "group of vectors" really just means "set of vectors". The word you translate as "group" may have a larger variety of meanings in the original language than "group" has in mathematical English.

Comment: You should edit the question to include the exact phrasing _in the original language_. Then there's a chance that someone who knows that language will come by and be able to weigh in.

Comment: I agree with @HenningMakholm. I would only add that it may also be that the book uses the word "group" informally, as in "a group of people" (which is really just a set of people).

Comment: Actually, one should always speak of a *family* of vectors in this context. *Group* in its algebraic meaning is certainly not correct (in the absence of a binary operation), but *set* may lead to unexpected exceptions. Note that the text in fact says $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ (a finite sequence  - or faimily - of vectors) and not $\{x_1,\ldots, x_k\}$ (a set of vectors).

Comment: If your text is not in English you may state the langugae (and original terminology) here for comparison. The "standard" translation of words is not always correct for mathematical terminology (e.g., German "Körper" id literally "body" but in math it is "field")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "group" is unusual in an English context, and I am quiet certain it has nothing to do with the algebraic object group.

Beware though that there are two slightly different ways to define linear independence, namely for families and for sets.

- A family $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ in $V$ is called linearly independent if 
  $\sum_{i \in I} a_i v_i = 0$ with $a_i \in K$, and $a_i=0$ for all but finitely many $a_i$ implies that $a_i=0$ for all $I$.
- A set $S$ in $V$ is called linearly independent if 
  $\sum_{v \in S} a_v v = 0$ with $a_v \in K$,  and $a_v=0$ for all but finitely many $v$, implies that $a_v=0$ for all $v \in S$.

The difference is that in the former some element of the vector space could appear more than once. For example you could have the family $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$ where $v_1= v_2 = (1,1)$ and $v_3= (-1, 2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and this is not independent as $1v_1 + (-1)v_2 + 0 v_3 = (0,0)$.

But the set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is independent as it is equal to $\{v_1, v_3\}$ as there are no repetitions in sets.

Thus, there is some need to be careful regarding what precisely is meant. It could be that your word "group" actually is the analogue of "family" in that language.

Comment: Word "family" is what I was looking for! It was hard for me to understand how we can take some vectors together and not make a set. Noone ever told me that there is a specific name for such thing. Thank you!